# INFO: Configuration 'compile' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'implementation' and 'api'

Tags: java, android, android-studio-3.0

I have downloaded a Camera app source code from GitHub. when I sync the project It will show 3 error. and also source code contains some dependency which I don't know how to replace. The main problem is androidX.

[image]

error 1

```
    ERROR: Failed to resolve: com.github.ittianyu:BottomNavigationViewEx:1.1.9
    Show in Project Structure dialog
    Affected Modules: app
```

error 2

```
    ERROR: Failed to resolve: com.github.eschao:android-ElasticListView:v1.0
    Show in Project Structure dialog
    Affected Modules: app
```

error 3

```
    INFO: Configuration 'compile' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'implementation' and 'api'.
    It will be removed soon. For more information see: http://d.android.com/r/tools/update-dependency-configurations.html
    Affected Modules: app
```

build.gradle(Module: app) file -

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

    android {
compileSdkVersion 28
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.cameraapplication"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 28
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
  }

    dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.0'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.1'

//Extra Dependency

testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
//Design library for Coordinator Layout and Toolbars
implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
//ExifInterface support
implementation 'com.android.support:exifinterface:28.0.0'
//design library for Coordinator Layout
implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
//Exo Player
implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer:2.10.5'
//cardview
implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0'
//recyclerview
implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'
//BottomNavigationViewEx library
implementation 'com.github.ittianyu:BottomNavigationViewEx:1.1.9'
//Circle ImageView
implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.2.0'
//elastic header
implementation 'com.github.eschao:android-ElasticListView:v1.0'
//material dialogs
implementation 'com.afollestad.material-dialogs:core:0.9.6.0'
//glide
implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.8.0'
annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.7.1'
implementation files('libs/aspectjrt-1.7.3 (1).jar')
//Universal image loader
implementation 'com.nostra13.universalimageloader:universal-image-loader:1.9.5'
compile files('libs/aspectjrt-1.7.3 (1).jar')

    }
```

build.gradle(project: CameraApplication) file -

```
    // Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

  buildscript {
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()

}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.1'

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
  }

  allprojects {
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()

}
  }

  task clean(type: Delete) {
delete rootProject.buildDir
  }
```

please tell me the solution
THANK YOU IN ADVANCE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ERROR: Failed to resolve: com.github.ittianyu:BottomNavigationViewEx:1.1.9
>   ERROR: Failed to resolve: com.github.eschao:android-ElasticListView:v1.0

In the top level file in the `allprojects` block you have to add the jitpack repo:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    }
}
```

> INFO: Configuration 'compile' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'implementation' and 'api'.

Remove this line

```
//compile files('libs/aspectjrt-1.7.3 (1).jar')
```

since you are already using `implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])`

Comment: Thank you for answering my questions

Comment: Can you upvote my question so that I can gain some reputation